# Update query in oracle with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update one table in oracle based on some condition.

It contains three fields. Name, Old_Address and New_Address

I have to store Previous New_Address into Old_Address when New_Address is changed.
My table contains some value like this:

Name: Sesuraj, Old_address: Chennai, New_Address: Delhi

Now i want to store new_address into old_address if new address is changed

```
update customer set Name='Siva',old_address=new_address,new_address='Mumbai'
```

Now result is:
Name: Siva, Old_address: Delhi, new_address: Mumbai

Now i have to stop update if new_address doesn't changed

```
update customer set Name='Guru',old_address=new_address,new_address='Mumbai'
```

I want out put like this:

Name: Guru, Old_address: Delhi, new_address: Mumbai

Comment: Tried using a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger?

Comment: Trigger is working. But desired output not came. If new_address=new_address means its also stored in old_address..

Comment: Use `If` statement to test `If new_address=new_address` then update else dont

Comment: Do you have a customer id column or any unique key there?

Comment: Yeah. Customer id is unique.

Answer (score 1):

I think for your desired output u have to update Old_address again to get the old one again in the output

```
update customer set Name='Guru',old_address='Delhi',new_address='Mumbai'
```

Answer (score 0):

try with where condition as below:

```
update customer set Name='Guru',old_address='Delhi',new_address='Mumbai' 
  where new_address<>'Mumbai'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 update customer set Name='Guru',old_add=(SELECT new_add from customer where cust_id=1),new_add='Jaipur' where cust_id=1 AND new_add<>'Jaipur'
```

Here "Jaipur" is your new address (User input)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `CASE` in your update to use the correct value depending if they match.

```
UPDATE customer SET name='Siva',
       new_address='Mumbai',
       old_address=CASE WHEN new_address<>'Mumbai'
                        THEN new_address
                        ELSE old_address END
       WHERE id=1;
```

Note that the value you want to update to goes into the query 2 times, once for updating `new_value` and once to compare with and update `old_value`;

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2f1a/1) (Edited, was broken)